# How to remove any screen when application install on device?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiapplication

I have a requirement that when application install on device then it will never show any screen and start a thread in background for 30 seconds. When complete that time then it will show a screen in application.

I mean to say that when we install an application on device then it show a Black Screen for a moment and read

> applicationDidFinishLaunching

after that it will don't show any screen. And in background we have start a thread for 30 seconds when that time period will complete then it will show a new view.

How do that? what is proper way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you question is some confusing.
basically what do you want?
1) do you not want to that black screen
or
2) you want to show a blank screen every time like a splash screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your app installs on device as per my understanding there is no way your app can start a background thread. You app is not active in the first place.

Once your app is invoked by the user, then you can start a background thread & do what needs to be done. Best way to start background threads in iOS is blocks -

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //do background task
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // update UI after task is done.
    });
});
```

This block based threading is perfect as [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) takes care of evenly distributing your task in case of multi-core processors, queuing tasks, memory handling of threads etc. all of this is handled for you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like some sort of daemon. If yes, it is not possible.